# A simple where clause in flutter/firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

Today I started experimenting with Firebase Live database. Maybe I'm thinking too much in sql terms. But what I want to do is get a record from my database where a value equals a variable with flutter. My table looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users').where('User_id', 1508)
```

Like I said. I'm a complete beginner when it comes to Live Databases. 
I hope someone can help me with this issue I'm having.

Kind regards,
Namanix

Comment: What's the problem ? That is quite unclear

Comment: It was? I'm sorry. I want to get a record out of the Firebase database with a specific user_id but i have no idea how

Comment: Usually you'll want to set that `User_id` as the key of your object. Instead of a GUID. So that you can do `.child('users/42')` instead of a query.

Answer (score 8):

According to firstore [docs](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-readme-tab-)

```
Firestore.instance
  .collection('talks')
  .where("topic", isEqualTo: "flutter")
  .snapshots()
  .listen((data) =>
    data.documents.forEach((doc) => print(doc["title"])));
```

Comment: This seems correct, but calling those "docs" is very generous. The Firebase documentation for Dart/Flutter is so bad that I question if soon they'll drop support altogether... I'm scared to proceed with this project. If they were more serious about dart/flutter support wouldn't they give more attention to their docs?

Comment: You are talking about the FirebaseStore but question is related to the real-time-database.

Comment: how can we use your code in widgets like whether to wrap in future builder and what to use `QuerySsnapshots` or `DocumentSnapshot`

Answer (score 2):

If you have the user id in a variable for example called:

```
String uid = currentUser.uid;
```

then you can do the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users/$uid')
```

**Update**
I think this is what you are asking about

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
                    .reference().child("users")
                    .orderByChild("User_id")
                    .equalTo($this.userId)
```

Comment: That won't work in my case. The user_id is in the record. The id in users/$uid is generated by firebase and not used by me.

Comment: I am confused. You do have it in your auth object

Comment: You literally said this `But what I want to do is get a record from my database where a value equals a variable with flutter`

Comment: The user_id that I want to search the database with is 1 deeper. users/-L9ozsSf-rtHDfwgHRrm/$uid.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then I think you are looking for orderByChild, I updated the answer

Comment: I mean equalTo, orderByChild is not important here

Comment: Hmmm i just tried it but still getting back null values. This is really hard to get my head around after 10+ years of SQL... `dynamic test = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users').equalTo('1508').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
           print(snapshot.value);
        });`

Comment: You need to add the key "User_id", else how will it know what equals to what

Comment: I mean  `FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users/User_id").equalTo(this.uid)`

Comment: How do i add a key to this line of code? Or do i need to add it in the database?

Comment: Still getting back null values. `FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users/User_id').equalTo('1508').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){print(snapshot.value);});`

Comment: It'd be much more performant to set `user_id` as key of the object instead of a guid.

Comment: I've just set the object key as the user_id and now it all works fine. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore
                .instance
                .collection('users') 
                .where("user_id", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)//  Your where condition here
                .get(), 
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['avatar']), //  Your valid data here
            );
          }).toList());
        },
      )),
    );
  }
```

Also refer: [How to use `StreamBuilder` and `FutureBuilder` for single and multiple documents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75148843/13431819)